# How to check Password and Confirm Password Same in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi can any one help how i can validate Password and Confirm Password Fields in AngularJS

Comment: Please read through Stackoverflow's guide on [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future questions.

Comment: please do some initial research before posting any question here. anyway below answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

there are so many ways you can achive this. one way is using directive

```
<input type="password" name="confirmPassword" 
    ng-model="registration.user.confirmPassword"
    required 
    compare-to="registration.user.password" />

<div ng-messages="registrationForm.confirmPassword.$error"
  ng-messages-include="messages.html"></div>
```

//Directive

```
var compareTo = function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
        otherModelValue: "=compareTo"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$validators.compareTo = function(modelValue) {
            return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
        };

        scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
            ngModel.$validate();
        });
    }
  };
};

module.directive("compareTo", compareTo);
```

[Reference](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/10/13/confirm-password-validation-in-angularjs.aspx)